# Use wordlist for Codeigniter captcha

Tags: codeigniter, captcha

I have a wordlist of dictionary words in .txt format. How can I use this with the **captcha_helper** instead of random characters? I've already extended the captcha_helper file but am having issues integrating my `wordlist.txt` file for use.

After doing some poking, I found a solution:

```
// This is the modified version in captcha_helper.php
if($word == ''){
    $wordsfile = '../words.php';
    $fp = fopen($wordsfile, 'r');
    $length = strlen(fgets($fp));
    $line = rand(1, (filesize($wordsfile)/$length)-2);

    if(fseek($fp, $length*$line) == -1) return FALSE;
    $word = trim(fgets($fp));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

But I noticed that sometimes the last letter would get cut off. Is there a way to make sure that the first and last letter never get placed outside of the bounding box?

Comment: Can you show what you've done, and explain the problems you're having?

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can use one function which pass your words randomly to the script to display..

i think this is better option.

instead to work wit